# Create-React-App - modify serviceWorker to poll for new updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on adding a requested feature to my SPA. We have some users who leave their tabs open to our application for long periods of time. We also push out frequent updates (sometimes 5x a day, as we're pre-revenue). I'm wondering if it's possible to modify the serviceWorker that comes installed with Create-React-App to run a polling loop (maybe every 10 minutes) to poll for new updates to the application, instead of only on initial page load.

This way, a user who leaves their tab open could receive update notifications without having to refresh.

Has anyone achieved something like this before, and know how I might implement that into the CRA serviceWorker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! In the `registerServiceWorker.js` file, I added a simple setInterval inside the callback for the `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` function:

```
// poll for live updates to the serviceWorker
pollingLoopInterval = setInterval(async () => {
    await registration.update();
}, POLLING_LOOP_MS);
```

Easy!

Comment: Did it turn out to be a good solution? I tried it and it works great, but I would like to know how was it as time went by

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be a good solution for me. It worked as expected, outside of running into the issue of our bundle being too large to work with the PWA, but that was a separate issue.