# How can you guarantee that a PWA is fully up-to-date using only built-in functionality, without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I've got a Service Worker in an offline-first PWA with users that frequently stay offline for hours or days at a time, on tablets that don't get restarted or ever close the app. When my users leave the app open for a while, they never end up with the latest updates, since the Service Worker caches it.

Is there any method for fetching the latest application ad-hoc without having to reload the entire page? I'm hoping this is a stupid question.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810978/create-react-app-modify-serviceworker-to-poll-for-new-updates It might be helpful for you.